# How to check relu gradient

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement ANN and I also wrote a numerical gradient check for backpropagation.
When I use sigmoid function, the numerical gradient check works correctly.
However, when I use relu activation, the gradient check fails.

The gradient I get is written as follows:

```
switch opts.act_function
    case 'relu'
        d_act = a{i} > 0;
    case 'sigmoid'
        d_act = a{i} * (1 - a{i});
end
```

My question is that there is no gradient at 0. If I set the subgradient of 0 to 0, is this correct?

Comment: What exactly fails? Or is the question only about what the gradient at `x=0` should be?

Comment: Fails to check the weight gradient. I use `dw = f(w + epsilon) - f(w - epsilon) / (2 * epsilon)` to check the gradient. When I use sigmoid activation, this is correct, but when I use relu activation, It fails. So, what is the correct gradient I should set when `x = 0`.

Answer (score 8):

Numerical checking with the ReLU function is known to have problems at `x = 0`.  If you recall, the ReLU function is defined such that `f(x) = max(0, x)`.  It is a ramp function where values less than 0 are clamped to 0 while values that are strictly positive retain the same value.

The problems encountered with numerically gradient checking functions like ReLU are commonly known as the problem of *kinks*.  Kinks refer to non-differentiable parts of an objective or activation function.  For the ReLU function, the derivative approaching from the left of `x = 0` and from the right of `x = 0` are **not** equal and so the derivative does not exist at `x = 0` or more colloquially, there is a *kink at `x = 0`*.

Even though you don't have gradients at 0, it is possible that for a given `w` and `epsilon`, you will calculate a non-zero gradient when performing gradient checking.  Take for example the case where `x = -1e-5` which is non-zero and consider the case when `epsilon = 1e-4`.  By using the centered difference approximation as seen in your comment, `f(x + epsilon) = f(-1e-5 + 1e-4) = f(9e-5) = 9e-5` given the definition of ReLU.  Similarly, `f(x - epsilon) = f(-1e-5 - 1e-4) = f(-1.1e-5) = 0` given the definition of ReLU.  Therefore if you tried to approximate the derivative:

```
(f(x + epsilon) - f(x - epsilon)) / (2*epsilon) = (9e-5 - 0) / 2e-4 = 0.45
```

The numerical gradient gives us 0.45 when it should theoretically be 0. Therefore, the numerical gradient cannot be relied on here for the case of small values towards `x = 0`.  You don't encounter this problem with the sigmoid function because it is a function that is differentiable everywhere, so for a sufficiently small `epsilon`, you should be able to achieve approximately the same value as the actual derivative of the function.

What you can do instead is **identify** when a numerical inaccuracy will occur.  What you can do is determine when `f(x + epsilon)` and `f(x - epsilon)` differ in sign which will give you an indication that you are crossing the kink at `x = 0`. You can then output a warning to the user that this situation has happened and that the numerical gradient should not be relied upon.  Otherwise, the gradient should be able to pass normally when both `f(x + epsilon)` and `f(x - epsilon)` are of the same sign.

Comment: What is the meaning of "when `f(x + epsilon)` and `f(x - epsilon)` differ in sign?" `f(x) = max(0, x)`. May it be `x+epsilon and x-epsilon` differ in sign?

Comment: No, when the sign of `f(x + epsilon)` and `f(x - epsilon)` differ in sign... in general.  When you calculate both quantities, examine whether both values are positive, both are negative or both are unequal in polarity.  If both values are unequal in polarity, then you will have a kink for the case of ReLU.  However as you have noticed, you can simplify to `x + epsilon` and `x - epsilon` as differing in polarity to see that there is a kink. This simplification is not generally true for all activation or objective functions. It just so happens that it works out with ReLU.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, when I do numerical check in neural network, what  I get is a square-loss function. Therefore `f(w + epsilon)` and `f(w - epsilon)` is always positive. How can I see there is a kink? Just when `w + epsilon` and `w - epsilon` differ in sign, there is a kink? `f(w + epsilon)` may equals `f(g(h(w + epsilon)))`, `f(x)` is the square loss, `g(x)` is the relu.

Comment: Your question is now misleading. It states you want to gradient check the ReLU function. What you're asking now is totally different than your original question.

Comment: OK. I will ask another question. Thanks a lot.